# Why does the image inside a scaled div become smaller instead of scaling with its parent?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a hover effect on a div, which scales the whole div slightly. That works well so far, but when i put an image inside that div, it becomes smaller instead of scaling with its parent.

I created a fiddle to illustrate the issue: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qotp1vnc/)

```
<main>
  <div class=" w-100 row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="base square clickable">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-around flex-column h-100">
            <img src="test.jpg" alt="Company" width="50%">
            <h4 class="mt-2">Company Name</h4>
            <h5 class="mt-2">Zusatz info</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

```
.base {
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

.square {
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    margin: 10px;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

.base img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: auto;
}

.base.clickable {
    transition: transform 300ms;
}

.base.clickable:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why the image doesn't scale properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`content{position: absolute;}`

remove the element from the normal document flow
so it does not scale with its parent

Comment: I see. Thank you, that solved the scaling issue. Now I just need to find a way to make that inner div relative :) That should be easy enough though

Comment: I don't get what do you mean by relative 
do you mean position if yes 
`position: relative; ` instead of `position:absolute;`

Comment: Yeah I know. Stil thanks for clarifying. I made those divs absolute for a reason, as those "cards" are part of something bigger. I just need to figure out how I can do the same thing with a relative layout.